# How to ignore specific css files from Web Essentials browser link save CSS functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, web-essentials

I am having issues with the "Save F12 Changes" feature of Web Essentials after changing some styling on my site.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SPpg.png

I found the cause of the issue to be the font awesome stylesheet reference I have: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

I found you can add css usage files to ignore in Options > Web Essentials > BrowserLink > CSS usage files to ignore, but I cannot figure out what to add in order to have the file ignored.

Currently I have tried adding `*font-awesome.css` with and without the asterisk. Does anyone know what I should have instead?